# whatweb doesn't check internal urls except '/' that listed under matches

Tags: ruby, fingerprint, fingerprinting

I am new to whatweb and I want to create my own plugin, I saw many plugins that use md5 on pictures of the website. 
For example Moxax-NPort-Device:

> { :md5=>"27829d70bb23c465d86b9c643cf534d3", :url=>"/logo.gif" },
>     { :md5=>"2f9af91da3dc3f192e26ac8f42db41bd", :url=>"/logo.gif" },

The problem that I found out is that, whatweb doesn't check those urls, I used wireshark and saw that there are no requests to there, moreover I tried to leave only those checks and whatweb stopped recognize Moxax-NPort-Device.

When I use my own plugin I can check on md5 of '/' but not on '/loginback.jpg' for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WhatWeb will follow URLs specified with :url within a matching hash when:

1. Aggressive mode (-a 3) is used and the plugin has already matched.
2. Aggressive mode (-a 4) is used regardless of whether the plugin has already matched.

By default WhatWeb uses passive mode (-a 1). This does not follow additional URLs.

See the following resources for more information:

- https://github.com/urbanadventurer/WhatWeb/wiki/Writing-WhatWeb-Plugins
- https://github.com/urbanadventurer/WhatWeb/wiki/How-to-develop-WhatWeb-plugins

Comment: Please post your entire plugin so that I can check it. A sample website for Moxax-NPort-Device would also be helpful.

Comment: I prefer not to share my plugin at this time, just remove all except the checks for logo.gif in Moxa-Nport-Device. A sample website is: http://81.82.194.157:5000/